# How to have Text-Shadow with Webkit gradient

Tags: html, css, shadow

When I use Text-Shadow with Webkit gradient, it appears to be on top of the text - instead of behind. I increased the shadow opacity to show this.

```css
#title {
  font-size: calc(15px + 9vw);
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, blue 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 8vh;
  text-shadow: -10px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 -10px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1),
                 -10px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<h3 id="title">Example</h3>
```

Comment: intresting but logical ... since you allowed the background to be seen through the text

Comment: you basically setting a background to the element (the box), making it take the text shape, having the color/fil-color of the text transparent, and having a text-shadow, as you may already know the text is in the inside of the element not outside so the background will be in the back as you may expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And idea is to create another layer with pseudo-element that you put behind.

```css
#title {
  font-size: calc(15px + 9vw);
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, blue 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 8vh;
  position:relative;
}
#title:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
    text-shadow: -10px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 -10px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1),
                 -10px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  z-index:-1
}
```

```html
<h3 id="title" data-text="Example">Example</h3>
```

And if you don't want to duplicate the text you can use both pseudo-element and define the text only in the attribute:

```css
#title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 8vh;
  font-size: calc(15px + 9vw);
  z-index: 0;
}

#title:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, blue 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

#title:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 
    -10px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
    -10px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 
    -10px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="title" data-text="Example"></h3>
```